# PHP: Upload Video File via Youtube API v3 that logins automatically without user interaction

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I would like to upload a video-file with PHP and the YouTube Data Api v3.
The PHP file should

1. automatically log in to the YouTube Data API
2. upload a video file

so that the user does not have to login manually.

The goal is to allow a user to be able to upload a video to YouTube via app or website without needing to login to google first.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php


if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/youtubeapi/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "%s"', __DIR__));
    }

require_once __DIR__ . '/youtubeapi/vendor/autoload.php';


putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service_credentials.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
]);
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();



// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Define the $video object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video($client);

// Add 'snippet' object to the $video object.
$videoSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet($client);
$videoSnippet->setCategoryId('22');
$videoSnippet->setDescription('Description of uploaded video.');
$videoSnippet->setTitle('Test video upload.');
$video->setSnippet($videoSnippet);

// Add 'status' object to the $video object.
$videoStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus($client);
$videoStatus->setPrivacyStatus('private');
$video->setStatus($videoStatus);

// TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
//       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
//       The maximum file size for this operation is 128GB.
$response = $service->videos->insert(
  'snippet,status',
  $video,
  array(
    'data' => file_get_contents("big_buck_bunny.mp4"),
    'mimeType' => 'video/*',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'
  )
);
print_r($response);

?>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors":
> [ { "domain": "youtube.header", "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",
> "message": "Unauthorized", "locationType": "header", "location":
> "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Unauthorized" } } in
> /homepages/37/d797893845/htdocs/development/sitesmedia/youtube/youtubeapi/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
> Stack trace: #0
> /homepages/37/d797893845/htdocs/development/sitesmedia/youtube/youtubeapi/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94):
> Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1
> /homepages/37/d797893845/htdocs/development/sitesmedia/youtube/youtubeapi/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176):
> Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2
> /homepages/37/d797893845/htdocs/development/sitesmedia/youtube/youtubeapi/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58):
> Google_Task_Runner->run() #3 /homepages/37/d797893845/ in
> /homepages/37/d797893845/htdocs/development/sitesmedia/youtube/youtubeapi/src/Google/Http/REST.php
> on line 118
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like YouTube does not support service accounts.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors

> **unauthorized (401)  youtubeSignupRequired** This error indicates that the user has an unlinked Google Account, which means that the user has
>   a Google Account but does not have a YouTube channel. Such users can
>   access many features that are dependent on user authorization, such as
>   rating videos or adding videos to a watch_later playlist. However, as
>   an example, the user would need a YouTube channel to be able to upload
>   a video. A user who has a Gmail account or an Android device is
>   certain to have a Google Account but may not have already linked that
>   Google Account to a YouTube channel.
>
> **This error is commonly seen if you try to use the OAuth 2.0 Service Account flow. YouTube does not support Service Accounts, and if you
>   attempt to authenticate using a Service Account, you will get this
>   error.**
>
> The YouTube API blog post introducing Google Account support also
>   discusses the youtubeSignupRequired error in more detail. Although the
>   blog post explains the error for API version 2.1, the meaning of the
>   error is still applicable.

Sounds like you're going to have to create a YouTube channel and then authenticate the requests that way.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application